# How do I write a windows batch script that do a checking on destination A folder, if file already exist, move to destination B folder?

Tags: batch-file

\source
1. abc.txt
2. ert1.txt
3. dfg2.txt
to check, if destA have file abc.txt
move ert1.txt and dfg2.txt to destA 
move abc.txt to destB
does this possible to perform via windows batch script?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you be more explicit and tell us what you have tried to do (with your code).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible,

if exist c:\desta\abc.txt ( 
move /Y c:\desta\abc.txt c:\destb\abc.txt
)